# What's the easiest way in *nix to wildcard a substring of a filename?

Tags: bash, unix

I want to do something like take the part of a wildcard match and use it similarly to a regex match. The command might look something like this

```
cat foo_* | python magic.py > magic_*
```

If my file names are

```
   foo_biz
   foo_baz
```

I want the output to be in files named

```
   magic_biz
   magic_baz
```

effectively changing the file names from `foo_*` to `magic_*`.

Is it possible to do this in a shell command? I'm using `bash`, but an answer for other shells is fine too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you can accomplish it but it takes a bit more work:

```
for f in foo_*; do python magic.py <"$f" >"${f/foo/magic}"; done
```

(Note: I also replaced the [useless use of cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat) with a `<` redirect.)

Answer (score 1):

Something just a little different than Gordon's excellent answer:

```
foos=(foo_*)
suffixes=(${foos[@]#foo_})
for sfx in "${suffixes[@]}"; do
    python magic.py < "foo_$sfx"  > "magic_$sfx"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ touch foo_{biz,baz}

$ ls foo_*
foo_baz  foo_biz

$ printf "%s\n" foo_* | sed 's/^foo_/magic_/'
magic_baz
magic_biz
```